Dynamically loading client components in Next.js
I'm working on developing a plugin system for an app I'm building in Next.js. I have an issue where the imported components are only rendering as server components and I cannot figure out how to prevent this from happening.
I have a custom server which injects the routes for plugin backend functionality:
import express from "express";
import next from "next";
import {config} from "dotenv";
import path from "path";
import Model from "@/lib/mongoose";
import PluginManager from "@utterr/plugin";
config({path: "./.env.local"});

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const app = next({dev});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

/* Plugin loading and initialization */
await PluginManager.loadPlugins(path.resolve(import.meta.dirname, "plugins"));
await PluginManager.initializePlugins(Model.Config, Model.ServerChannel, Model.ServerChannelData);

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    PluginManager.useRouters(server);

    server.use((req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});

The plugin manager searches the plugin directory to find the plugins:
import {
    ChannelDataModel,
    ChannelModel,
    ConfigModel,
    IDefaultChannel,
    IServerChannel,
    LoadedPlugin
} from "./types";
import * as nodePath from "path";
import * as fs from "node:fs";
import {Express} from "express";
import {FC} from "react";

class _PluginManager {
    private plugins: {[key: string]: LoadedPlugin} = {};
    private pluginDirectory: string = "";

    public constructor() {}

    private async findPlugins (): Promise<string[]> {
        const a: string[] = [];

        const plugins = fs.readdirSync(this.pluginDirectory);
        for (const plugin of plugins) {
            const f= fs.lstatSync(nodePath.resolve(this.pluginDirectory, plugin));
            // Check is directory or symlink
            if (f.isDirectory() || f.isSymbolicLink()) {
                // Check for package json
                if (fs.existsSync(nodePath.resolve(this.pluginDirectory, plugin, "package.json"))) {
                    // This is a valid plugin
                    a.push(plugin);
                } else {
                    // Scan one level deeper
                    const subPlugins = fs.readdirSync(nodePath.resolve(this.pluginDirectory, plugin));
                    for (const subPlugin of subPlugins) {
                        const subF = fs.lstatSync(nodePath.resolve(this.pluginDirectory, plugin, subPlugin));
                        if (subF.isDirectory() || subF.isSymbolicLink()) {
                            if (fs.existsSync(nodePath.resolve(this.pluginDirectory, plugin, subPlugin, "package.json"))) {
                                // This is a valid plugin
                                a.push(`${plugin}/${subPlugin}`);
                            } else {
                                console.warn(`Invalid plugin ${plugin}/${subPlugin}`);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (subPlugins.length === 0) {
                        console.warn(`Invalid plugin ${plugin}`);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(`Found ${a.length} plugins.`);
        return a;
    }

    private async loadPlugin (path: string): Promise<void> {
        // Leave template strings. They prevent a warning from appearing in the next dev server.
        const pkg = await import(`${nodePath.resolve(this.pluginDirectory, path, "package.json")}`);
        const module = await import(`${nodePath.resolve(this.pluginDirectory, path, "dist/src/index.js")}`);
        if (module.default.utterrPlugin) {
            this.plugins[pkg.name] = {
                name: pkg.name,
                version: pkg.version,
                plugin: new module.default.utterrPlugin()
            };
            console.log(`Loaded plugin ${pkg.name}@${pkg.version}`);
        } else throw new Error("Not an utterr plugin");
    }

    public async loadPlugins (directory: string): Promise<void> {
        this.pluginDirectory = directory;

        const paths = await this.findPlugins();

        for (const path of paths) {
            await this.loadPlugin(path);
        }
    }

    public async initializePlugins (configModel: ConfigModel, channelModel: ChannelModel, channelDataModel: ChannelDataModel): Promise<void> {
        for (const plugin in this.plugins) {
            const b = await this.plugins[plugin].plugin.initialize(configModel, channelModel, channelDataModel);
            if (!b) {
                console.error(`Failed to initialize ${this.plugins[plugin].name}`);
                process.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public useRouters (server: Express): void {
        for (const plugin in this.plugins) {
            server.use(`/plugin/${plugin}`, this.plugins[plugin].plugin.getRouter());
        }
    }

    public getDefaultChannels() : IDefaultChannel[] {
        const defaults: IDefaultChannel[] = [];

        console.log(this.plugins);

        for (const plugin in this.plugins) {
            console.log(plugin);
        }

        for (const plugin in this.plugins) {
            console.log(`Here ${plugin}`);
            console.log(`Defaults for ${plugin}: `, this.plugins[plugin].plugin.getDefaultChannels());
            this.plugins[plugin].plugin.getDefaultChannels().forEach(channel => {
                defaults.push(channel)
            });
        }

        console.log(defaults);

        return defaults;
    }

    public getChannelTypes (): string[] {
        const channelTypes = [];

        for (const plugin in this.plugins) {
            const types = this.plugins[plugin].plugin.getChannelTypes();

            for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                if (!types[i].startsWith(plugin))
                    throw new Error(`Channel type not prefixed with plugin name "${plugin}"`);
                channelTypes.push(types[i]);
            }
        }

        return [];
    }

    public getWindow (channel: IServerChannel): FC<{channel: IServerChannel}> {
        "use client";
        const plugin = channel.type.split(":")[0];
        return this.plugins[plugin].plugin.getWindow();
    }

    public getSidebar(channel: IServerChannel): FC<{channel: IServerChannel}> {
        "use client";
        const plugin = channel.type.split(":")[0];
        return this.plugins[plugin].plugin.getSidebar();
    }

    public getPlugins (): {[key: string]: LoadedPlugin} {
        return this.plugins;
    }
}

declare global {
    var PluginManager: _PluginManager;
}

if (!globalThis.PluginManager) {
    globalThis.PluginManager = new _PluginManager();
}

export default globalThis.PluginManager;

export * from "./types";

And the plugin itself exports a class the implements a common Plugin interface:
import {
    IDefaultChannel,
    InitFunction,
    IPlugin,
    IServerChannel,
} from "@utterr/plugin";
import {FC} from "react";
import Window from "./client/Window";
import Sidebar from "./client/Sidebar";
import {PluginServer} from "./server/router";
import pkg from "../package.json";

enum ChannelType {
    text = "text"
}

class TextPlugin implements IPlugin {
    private initialized: boolean = false;
    private server: PluginServer | null = null;

    // This function can be marked as async if needed
    public initialize: InitFunction = (configModel, channelModel, channelDataModel) => {
        try {
            this.server = new PluginServer(configModel, channelModel, channelDataModel);
            this.initialized = true;
            return true;
        } catch {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public getRouter() {
        if (!this.initialized) throw new Error("Plugin not initialized");
        return this.server!.getRouter();
    }

    public getChannelTypes () {
        if (!this.initialized) throw new Error("Plugin not initialized");
        return [ChannelType.text];
    }

    public getDefaultChannels(): IDefaultChannel[] {
        if (!this.initialized) throw new Error("Plugin not initialized");
        return [{
            name: "general",
            type: `${pkg.name}:${ChannelType.text}`,
            category: "General"
        }];
    }

    public getWindow (): FC<{channel: IServerChannel}> {
        if (!this.initialized) throw new Error("Plugin not initialized");
        return Window;
    }

    public getSidebar(): FC<{channel: IServerChannel}> {
        if (!this.initialized) throw new Error("Plugin not initialized");
        return Sidebar;
    }
}

export default {
    utterrPlugin: TextPlugin
}

Window and Sidebar work the same exact way, so I'll only include Sidebar.
"use server";

import "./style.css";
import {FC} from "react";
import {IServerChannel} from "@utterr/plugin";
import Badge from "./components/Badge";

const Sidebar: FC<{channel: IServerChannel}> = ({channel}) => {
    console.log(typeof window === "undefined" ? "server" : "client");

    return <div className="w-full h-max">
        <Badge channel={channel}/>
    </div>;
}

export default Sidebar;

And here's the badge component:
"use client";

import {FC} from "react";
import {IServerChannel} from "@utterr/plugin";

const Badge: FC<{channel: IServerChannel}> = ({channel}) => {
    console.log(typeof window === "undefined" ? "server" : "client");

    return <p className="py-2 px-4"><span className="text-lg text-gray-500">#</span> {channel.name}</p>;
}

export default Badge;

The component is rendered on the server side using this server component:
import {FC} from "react";
import {Separator} from "@utterr/ui";
import PluginManager from "@utterr/plugin";

interface ChannelListProps {
    serverSlug: string;
}

const ChannelList: FC<ChannelListProps> = async ({serverSlug}) => {
    const s = await Model.Server.findOne({ _id: serverSlug }).exec();
    const channels = await Model.ServerChannel.find({server: serverSlug}).exec();

    return <div className="w-[300px] h-screen border-r overflow-y-scroll no-scroll">
        <p className="p-2 text-2xl">{s?.name}</p>
        <Separator/>
        {channels.map(channel => {
            const Component = PluginManager.getSidebar(channel);
            return <Component key={channel._id.toString()} channel={channel} />
        })}
    </div>
}

export default ChannelList;

From here, the component is rendered properly, however, "server" is printed to the console in my IDE twice, but nothing is printed to the console in the browser. Is there anyway to get react and/or next to understand that it's a client component?
I've tried a ton of things, starting with making the Sidebar component a client component, but still prints server to IDE console.
I've tried passing the server component to a client component to treat it as a client component.
I've verified that the typescript compiler is keeping the directives in the dist folder.
I've looked through countless Next.js questions and docs and have found nothing.
